# kinetic js crash on resize ipad

Tags: ipad, crash, resize, kineticjs

I use this code to resize the stage. On desktop everything is fine but the Ipad safari and chrome crashes. I tried to delete some other stuff and figured at that it can only be the resize that forces the crash. Strange allthough that this code worked a while ago and I was very surprised that it doesn't now. Anyone got an idea or maybe another method of resizing?
Thanks in advance

```
        window.onresize = function(event) {  
        stage.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        stage.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
        stage.draw();   
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're triggering stage.draw() hundreds of times per second.  KineticJS v4.5.5 will resolve this problem with the stage.batchDraw() method, which hooks draws into the animation engine for performance.  This way, if you call stage.batchDraw() hundreds of times per second via mousemove, the stage will only get drawn about 60 times per second.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the iPad doesn't support `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` (I know not all mobile devices support it), so your code could be crashing by trying to set the stage width and height to an `undefined` number.

You'll have to use an alternative to setting the stage to the screen size.

You could try something like:

```
if (window.innerWidth) {
  width = window.innerWidth;
  height = window.innerHeight;
} else {
  width = screen.width;
  height = screen.height;
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, you'll have to look into other ways to handle different screen dimensions. I came across this article a while back: http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/